# Use jquery :contains and and .eq() to modify text style within specific div

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to combine the use of :contains and .eq() to search for text within a specific div?

I currently use the following two statements which create jquery statements based upon values grabbed from the URL by PHP $_GET[].

The first simply checks for link text matching the current $platformString and turns it white.

```
$(\"a:contains('". $platformString . "')\").css(\"color\", \"#ffffff\");
```

The second shows and hides a div based upon a known value stored in section.

```
$(\".sidebar_content\").eq(" . $section .").toggle();
```

The problem is that there can be multiple matches of $platformString within other hidden divs, once these are matched they are also turned white.

Can I combine the two statements to simply highlight the $platformString within the current $section?

Many thanks for any advice you are able to provide.

Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if i understand you correctly, but..

have you tried "a:visible:contains()" ?

This should only match the elements that are visible and contains the specified text.

Comment: Fantastic answer, this solution is perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This will search all the div's on the page for the text contained in `platformString` and wrap them in  tags.

```
var platformString = "replaceMe";

$('div').html(function() {
   return $(this).html().replace(new RegExp(platformString, "ig"), '<strong>$&</strong>'));
});
```

It's similar to "highlighting" just replace `<strong>` with another kind of tag you wish to use.. maybe a `<span>` with a class for some custom effects?

EDIT: replace `searchString` with `$&` - matches the searched text and preserves capitalization

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the other one provided me with a simpler solution but I appreciate your input. Kind regards.